# Open Form with Modal or Popup Window

Tags: vba, ms-access

Struggling a bit with this, I have a datasheet form which lists the ID and other info for each record. So far I have found some VBA code which will open each ID as a hyperlink and pass that into another form.

The problem I have is I wanted the form to open in a popup or modal window, my code so far is:

```
Private Sub ID_Click()
    Dim varWhereClause As String
    varWhereClause = "ID = " & Me!ID
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Copy Of test", , , varWhereClause
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9):

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Copy Of test", , , varWhereClause, ,acDialog
```

Though this will be pop-up and modal.

Comment: Actually, using acDialoog means the form is dialog, but NOT popup. There is a difference between modal forms and dialog forms. And there is a difference between dialog forms and popup forms (and in fact a big difference between model forms and popup forms also!). So, a model form is <> to a dialog form. And a popup form is <> to a model form. They each have a VERY different behavior and different use case. For example a popup form can be displayed on top of other forms but NOT require to have the focus (as a result a popup form is often used for wizard type of forms or help type displays).

Comment: If you're going to put a long message correcting something someone said, at least be right. I made no attempt to indicate that modal and pop-up are synonyms, I simply indicated that using acDialog opens as a pop-up and modal. [AcWindowMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195725.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

A small disadvantage of `acDialog` and `.PopUp` is that the form opens as window outside the access main window. That's why I prefer to use just `.Modal` if possible.

If you just want to block other open forms you can do a `Me.Modal = True` even temporarily in the open event of your form.

The disadvantage of `.Modal` is that it will not wait. `DoCmd.OpenForm , , , , , acDialog` doesn't return until the form is closed. Such a synchronous call can be very useful sometimes.

To do an `acDialog/PopUp` like call that stays **inside** the access main window you can use a little trick inside your form:

```
Private bFormOpen As Boolean

Public Sub ShowModal()
    SetFocus ' Make the form visible

    On Error GoTo ForcedClose
    bFormOpen = True
    Do While bFormOpen ' Wait until the form is closed
        Sleep 50
        DoEvents
    Loop

ForcedClose:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    bFormOpen = False

End Sub
```

You can than instantiate your form like this:

```
Dim f As New Form_Name

f.Modal = True
Call f.ShowModal

Set f = Nothing
```